# Magento multi website not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, nginx

I am trying to configure multiwebsite setup using magento 2.3.5 on nginx webserver on my localsystem.

The main website is http://www.myshop.com
and other is supposed to be http://myshop1.myshop.com

whenever I hit http://myshop1.myshop.com, It redirects to http://www.myshop.com

My Host Entries

127.0.0.1       *.myshop.com 
127.0.0.1       www.myshop.com 
127.0.0.1       myshop.com

I have made a nginx config as follows-:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myshop.com www.myshop.com *.myshop.com *.myshop1.myshop.com;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /home/kitchenlogsnew/myshop;
  include /home/kitchenlogsnew/myshop/nginx.conf.sample;
}
~
```

My store and web configuration in magento is as follows-:

[image: This is store config]

[image: This is url config]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure Nginx to single MAGENTO instance for running multiple stores (domains)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59678/configure-nginx-to-single-magento-instance-for-running-multiple-stores-domains)

Comment: Beautiful part is that I am not getting any error messages in nginx logs . But it simply redirects due to above config.